# Quering connection of Custom Audience to Ad Groups in Facebook Ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

What is the best way to get the Ad Groups using a Custom Audience in Facebook Ads Api?

Ads API provides a way to query connections for most objects. For example you could get all Ad Groups of an Ad Set by GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/{ad_set_id}/adgroups. I couldn't find something simular in [documentation of Custom Audiences](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting).

I could query all Ad Groups of Ad Accounts the Custom Audience belongs to and check the targeting field of Ad Groups. But this would generate a lot of requests to facebook API which isn't in my and facebooks interest. Isn't their a better way to get this information?

In particular I like to know which Custom Audiences aren't used in any Ad Groups anymore. I have to delete them to not getting problems with limit of 500 Custom Audiences per Ad Account.

Comment: there is no such documented method to know this.